# VB.Net: Adding to a List While Iterating

Tags: vb.net, list, loops, for-loop, collections

I am trying to figure out a way to add to a list that's being iterated through...

Example Code (Calling `test()`:

```
Dim listOfString As New List(Of String)

Public Sub test()
    For Each aString in listOfString
          getNumber(aString)
     Next
End Sub

Public Sub getNumber(theString as String)
     'Does Something
     listOfString.add(Something)
End Sub
```

My goal is to continue to add elements onto the end of `listOfString` while continuing to iterate through it until it gets to the end. I'm getting a `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` error on my actual code. Thanks for the time!

Comment: The error explains clearly that you cannot do that. Add the elements to a different list then merge.

Comment: What confuses you about the error message?  If you change the collection the enumerator is invalidated (by design)

Comment: I was hoping for ideas around it

Comment: As I have said, use a different list and at the end of the loop Union or Concat

Comment: @Steve But I also want the items added to the list to be iterated over

Comment: Easiest is to enumerate copy of the collection `For Each aString in listOfString.ToList()`

Comment: What exactly is the end goal here?  I see your explanation in the comments to Alex B.'s answer below, but still you end up with an endless loop (start with a list, do some process to create a new list, then iterate through that list, and keep doing that).  What is the 'stop' criteria?

Comment: @Andarta the stop criteria is when both lists are empty... AKA when all childs of all parents have been gotten

Answer (score 1):

I want to add something which has not been stated in the comments:

Look at your code and "play" CLR:

1. Create a new List of string `listOfString`
2. (not in your code but:) Add 1 start items to your list
3. Start looping the list For Each item in `listOfString` -> Contains 1 Item
4. Add 1 item to the list -> contains 2 items
5. End of `listOfString` reached? No we got 2 items only 1 item is "looped" -> Continue For Each
6. Add 1 item to the list -> contains 3 items
7. End of `listOfString` reached? Now we got 3 items only 2 items are "looped" -> Continue For Each
8. Add 1 item to the list -> contains 4 items
9. End of `listOfString` reached? Now we got 4 items only 3 items are "looped".
   ....

I guess you got the point here. If .NET would allow your approach you will end up with an infinite loop here.

What you can do has already been said in the comments. Create two lists, add the new items to the second list and `Union` or `Concat` both later.

Comment: My thing is I need the items added to the list to be iterated over at the same time. I was thinking about making two list. While iterating over list 1, put contents in list 2 then set list 1 to nothing. While iterating over list 2, put elements in list 1 then set list 2 to nothing. Then call the function recursively to iterate through whichever list isn't empty. Also, once items are iterated over I don't need them anymore... Does my logic make sense?

Comment: I´m not sure that I understood your approach correctly. Can you be more specific on *what* you want to achieve? Can you give a real example of what your start list looks like, which items you want to add and what the expected result is?

Comment: I have an initial list, say `(A,B,C,D)`. Think of each letter as a primary key. So `A` might have `(Y,Z)`. And then `Y` might have `(5,6)`. Kind of like a hierarchy. So for the first iteration of the loop I want it to do that process for each letter. Second iteration (in the case of `A`) do it for `(Y,Z)`. Third iteration (case of `Y`) do it for `(5,6)` and so on.

Comment: 'will answer you tomorrow I´m too tired right now ;)